# Making modular program which support dll extension in C#

Tags: c#

I am creating a program which shows a form with a text field and activate button, there are certain code which are entered by the user in the text field and on clicking activate button it does the work based on the code inputted by user.

I have successfully created a form and in the activate button click event it calls the method of another class (named Output) like below

```
Output o = new Output();//Created object for output class  
o.effect(s.Text);//here effect() is function of Output and s is textfield
```

And in Output class's effect() function

```
void effect(String str)  
{  
    switch(str)  
    {  
        case "code1": Console.Write("you enter code1");  //all the things to be done if code1 input    
        break;  
        ...  
        ...  
        default: ...;  
        break;  
    }  
}
```

The above classes were successfully compiled and run properly. But now I want to make a dll support for this program so that whenever I have to add more code I can just easily create a new dll (Say, Outputversion2.dll) in which there are code like above Output class which can be entered in main program form.

Something like a code extension...

I don't want to mistakenly damage the main program by editing every time to add more codes that's why I thought of it.

Hope you understand what I want to do.
I am just beginner with c# , just learned a month ago.
Sorry for any Grammar error, my English is also not so good.

Thank U.

Comment: Sorry if Title do not match the  content. I was not able to think a good title for this post.

Comment: Extensibility is actually a rather large topic to tackle, I wouldn't recommend it if you just started a month ago. But in case you still want to try it, have a look at the https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx Managed Extensibility Framework (part of .NET)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. If you're hoping to be able to dynamically add new DLLs, each with a set of handlers (i.e. cases), then you should probably use the [Managed Extensibility Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx). Otherwise, if what you are trying to do is to simply have all handlers in one separate DLL that can be replaced at any time, you should place the Output class in a Class Library, which will compile into a DLL; you can then swap out versions of this DLL without worrying about changing the main program, so long as you don't change the interface (the classes and their functions' return types and parameters; you can change the code inside the function as much as you want).

Also, if your worried about destabilizing the main program, I would recommend keeping backups of the source code, and not releasing new versions until you have fully tested them multiple times.

I hope this helps.